# CSS Card buttons :hover adds padding/margin to the whole card (i think)

Tags: css

CSS learner here. 
Im making frontend mentor exersise with 3 card preview. After i added the hover state to the buttons the whole card is expending by few pixels when i hover over it. Cards are made with flexbox. I tried to locate the source of this, but so far im unable. 
Here is the the whole thing. 
https://codepen.io/Dungeoner999/pen/JjELjmB

`/*-----*/`

Do anyone know why this is happening and what can i do to make the cards size fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**.btn-1** does not have border. While **.btn-1:hover** has `1px` border. To fix the issue, give it `1px transparent` border.

```
.btn-1 {
  color: var(--orange);
  border: 1px solid  transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put border to your ***.btn*** style and problem solved:) Card get's bigger right now because of one extra pixel from hover

```
border: var(--tWhite) 1px solid;
```